# Align text to right of upper text (which is aligned to left). Widths unknown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a slogan text to the right of the header title, while the header title is aligned to the left

Both widths are unknown, and font-size set in em's

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|THIS IS THE LARGE HEADER TITLE                         |
|                - small slogan                         |
|--------------------------------------------------------

<div id="header">
<h1>This is the large header title</h1>
<p>Small slogan here</p>
</div>
```

Can this be done in CSS, when width is not set? Or how can I achieve this?

Slogan width: "relative" + text-align: right or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If extra markup is acceptable...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/44Us8/1/)

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>This is the large header title</h1>
        <p>Small slogan here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
p {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you float the header left, it will shrink the div container and allow you to use text-align on the paragraph:

```
#header  {
    float:left;
}
#header p {
    text-align:right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vt5vw/)**